# TiledSprite not work onAreaTouched

Tags: android, andengine

onAreaTouched not work, I can place a method onAreaTouched a Sprite that extends Entity class and then register it in the scene:   mScene.registerTouchArea (mMENU);

My entity class is:

```
public class Menu extends Entity implements ITouchArea{

private TiledSprite mPlaySprite;

private final ParallelEntityModifier mMoveInModifie2 = new ParallelEntityModifier(
        new ScaleAtModifier(1f, 5f, 1f, 0.5f, 0.5f), 
        new FadeInModifier(0.1f));



public Menu() {

}

public void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.mPlaySprite = new TiledSprite(0, 0, ResourceManager.MenuoptionTextureRegion,
            ResourceManager.getActivity().getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            /* In the event the mute button is pressed down on... */
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {

                Log.e("pollito","Prueba touch");
            }

            return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                    pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };          
    this.mPlaySprite.setCurrentTileIndex(0);
    this.mPlaySprite.setPosition(ResourceManager.getInstance().cameraWidth*0.5f, ResourceManager.getInstance().cameraHeight * 0.5f );
    this.attachChild(this.mPlaySprite);


    this.setVisible(false);     
}

public void show() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    mMoveInModifie2.reset();
    this.mPlaySprite.registerEntityModifier(mMoveInModifie2);

}

public void hide() {
    this.setVisible(false);
}

}
```

In my MainActivity  in method onCreateScene :

```
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) {

    ResourceManager.loadMenuResources();

    mScene = new Scene();

    mScene.setBackground(new Background(0.9f,0.9f,0.9f));
    mMenu.init();

    mScene.registerTouchArea(mMenu);
    mScene.attachChild(mMenu);   

    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(mScene);
}
```

Comment: Where you called mScene.registerTouchArea(Menu's mPlaySprite)?

Comment: ok thanks,
modify the code  this is:

              mScene.registerTouchArea (mMenu.mPlaySprite);